Use Sauvola for a already binarized image
I want to use Sauvola for multiple iteration of the same image with different parameters. However, it doesn't work, because the image doesn't change at all in the second binarization, as seen in the picture:

It might be because Sauvola can't be used for a monochromatic image, as there is nothing to change, but I couldn't find an actual statement to support or contradict that.
My code:
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import filters
to_binarize_images_path = "../Data/shabby-images/to-binarize/"
binarized_images_path = "../Data/shabby-images/binarized-images-i1/"

for file in os.listdir(to_binarize_images_path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        break
    image = cv2.imread(to_binarize_images_path + file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    thresh_sauvola = filters.threshold_sauvola(image, window_size=13, k=0.2)
    mono_image = image > thresh_sauvola
    mono_image = (mono_image * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    
    thresh_sauvola2 = filters.threshold_sauvola(mono_image, window_size=301, k=0.9)
    mono_image2 = mono_image > thresh_sauvola2
    mono_image2 = (mono_image2 * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
    axes[0].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    axes[0].set_title('Original')
    axes[1].imshow(mono_image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    axes[1].set_title('Binarisiert')
    axes[2].imshow(mono_image2, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    axes[2].set_title('Binarisiert 2')

